# Как поменять местами элементы массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
let arr = ['вс', 'пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб']
```

Как проще всего добавить 0 элемент `'вс'` в конец массива?

У меня получилось так:

```js
let shiftElem = arr.shift()
arr.push(shiftElem)
```

Возможно ли сделать проще?

Answer (score 4):

Самый очевидный и простой вариант:

```js
let arr = ['вс', 'пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб'];
console.log(arr.concat(arr.splice(0,1)));
```

Comment: 1. И чем же он простой? 2. Тут создаётся новый массив, а старый портится.

Comment: @Qwertiy: вариант прост тем, что долго не задержится здесь, будучи не отмеченным, как решение. Это же очевидно. Мне как раз пары-тройки ответов удалённых не хватает, для ровного счёта :)

Answer (score 4):

В плане простоты кода проще записать это в одну команду:

```js
let arr = ['вс', 'пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб']

arr.push(arr.shift())

console.log(arr)
```

По производительности тоже должно быть довольно хорошо. Единственный вариант, когда это может быть хуже ручного цикла - это если при удалении элемента произойдёт перевыделение памяти, но такая ситуация довольно маловероятна.

PS: Ну и не стоит забывать, что асимптотика всё равно у этого кода линейная.

Answer (score 1):

Если прям очень хочется гарантированно без выделения памяти, то можно сделать так (хотя я бы не стал без данных профилирования):

```js
let arr = ['вс', 'пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб']

let x = arr[0]
arr.copyWithin(0, 1)
arr[arr.length - 1] = x

console.log(arr)
```